# flush() doesn't work in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm new in Doctrine 2. I have a big problem on beginning, I didn't find any solution in Google.
I want to keep tree in DB. I found a NestedSet plugin (https://github.com/blt04/doctrine2-nestedset). I downloaded it, and I tried to build tree. I tried this way (it's the same like in the documentation):

```
    $config = new \DoctrineExtensions\NestedSet\Config($entityManager, 'src\File');
    $nsm = new \DoctrineExtensions\NestedSet\Manager($config);

    $mainFolder = new \src\File();
    $mainFolder->setName('Folder 1');
    $nsm->createRoot($mainFolder);
```

But it does nothing. I looked iside createRoot() function, and I figured out that function flush() doesen't work:

```
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush()
```

But I don't know why. It doesen't throw an Exception, and returns nothing.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That extension you found has 36 commits and was updated a year ago. You might wanna check out this extension https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions which has 1312 commits and was updated 2 days ago. You can use this to build a tree: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md

The problem probably is because you don't do a persist() on any of your entities (unless that extension takes care of that, but an extension shouldn't do this actually).

Comment: I digged a bit, and I think the problem isn't related with the plugin, but with Doctrine 2, because I can't add a row using

    `$mainFolder = new \src\File();
    $mainFolder->setName('Folder 1');
    $entityManager->persist($mainFolder);
    $entityManager->flush();`

Comment: I noticed you changed `$this->getEntityManager()` to `$entityManager`. Please update your question with all the relevant code. Also do a `var_dump()` on the entitymanager to see if it is an actual entity manager. And on your object: `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($mainFolder);`

Comment: `$this->getEntityManager()` is used in the createRoot() method.
`$entityManager` is used in code from the first post.

I added Doctrine's var_dump() and it returned this: http://pastebin.com/ptFZBVgS